# How do I serialize better using boost?

Tags: c++, serialization, visual-c++, boost, boost-serialization

i'm using boost C++ library to serialize data into binary and text file. But while serializing data it adds headers which I do not want. Is there any way to remove these headers?
for example :

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>

class Frame{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, Frame& f, const unsigned int version) {
    ar& f.x;
    ar& f.y;
    ar& f.z;
}

uint32_t main () {
    Frame f={1,2,3};
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("TextFile.txt",std::ios::out);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive write(ofs,boost::archive::no_header);
    write << f;
    ofs.close();
}
```

it's result will be:

```
00 1 2 3
```

but what i want is:

```
1 2 3
```

even after using no_header while creating text_oarchive object it still gives this '00'
I want to get rid of it. So, how to remove this?

Comment: why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: if you just want to write some humanreadable text to a file you can overload an `operator<<` for your type. If you want to be able to later restore the serialized object more is needed

Comment: *(Boost archive) adds headers which I do not want*  Then you will need to not use Boost archive.

Comment: @Eljay any other method other than boost::archive within boost library?

Comment: I dont understand the question, because the contents of the file are not meant for you, they are meant to be deserialized later. If you merely want something written to a file so you can read it in a text editor you dont need to use boost-archive

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ok I understood now, but I'm just asking if there is better option or not.

Comment: better than what? What are you trying to achieve? Why is the header disturbing you?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number because I'll be adding my own headers and I'll be adding different types of frames too. So, there will be 2 headers , so I just wanna know if I can serialize without that.

Comment: You can, by not using Boost archives.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else, I think you should not confuse Boost Archives with streams. Just... write the code yourself.

But, if this helps, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html shows how you can suppress version information:

**[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b20f41bdcc80bdb7)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::archive::archive_flags;

struct Frame {
    int  x, y, z;
    void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar& x& y& z; }
};

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(Frame, boost::serialization::level_type::object_serializable)

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout, archive_flags::no_header);
    oa << Frame {1, 2, 3};
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3
```